# ASM in C gives an error with -std=c99

Tags: c, assembly, c99, inline-assembly

I'm now willing to compile my project with `-std=c99` and I'm facing an error I'm not understanding for the moment. This line :

```
my_type* td = ({ register kmy_type* arg0 asm("eax"); arg0; });
```

gives me the following error only in C99 :

```
warning: ISO C forbids nested functions
error: syntax error before ‘asm’
error: ‘arg0’ undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: for each function it appears in.)
warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions
```

Any clues are welcome to help me understanding what this means. I didn't write this line and I'm also not sure to understand what is its purpose.

Comment: Try using -std=gnu99 instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line

```
my_type* td = ({ register my_type* arg0 asm("eax"); arg0; });
```

should get a value in the `eax` register, interpreted as a pointer, into `td` variable. However, it uses lots of GNU extensions, particularly statement expressions and this use of `asm` (explicit register allocation). I'd suggest you to switch to -std=gnu99 (or whatever it's called). Otherwise, you might want to play with double underscores (eg. `asm` -> `__asm`) or the `__extension__` keyword, but I don't know if it'll help in c99 mode.

Edit: I just tried it and simply changing `asm` to `__asm` works.

Comment: Thanks - I just ran into this problem as well.  It's not obvious that C99 is the problem!

Answer (score 3):

`asm()` doesn't seem to work with `-std=c99`. It's a bad idea in my opinion, since the standard actually suggests that compilers support an `asm()` keyword, but it isn't mandatory.

I suggest that you use `-pedantic` instead.

Comment: Try `-std=gnu99` instead, this enables support for the `asm()` function.

Comment: @gbmhunter Same for the 11 standard (i.e. `gnu11` and `gnu++11`). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -2):

The problem there is not asm, looks like its arg0

Comment: No, the problem is asm; arg0 is just a variable with declaration containing asm, therefore the compiler is confused about it.